# Is there a way to set local paths for 'private' node modules within 'private' node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

e.g. where my app looks like:

```
app.js
modules/
  log/
    core.js
    _modules/
      color.js
node_modules/
```

I know I can set the modules directory of app.js via:

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = "./modules";
require("module").Module._initPaths();

require('log')('success');
```

However, running the same code pattern again within modules/log for _modules, like so:

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = "./_modules";
require("module").Module._initPaths();

var yellow = require('color').yellow;
```

causes the compiler to overwrite the process.env.NODE_PATH variable previously set in app.js, as process is presumably a global variable belonging to app.js.

So, is there a way to set a NODE_PATH or comparable within the context of a module?

Comment: why do you need to do this?  You can either just require('./color.js') or use __dirname

Comment: @WakeskaterX sure, at this level of complexity it's not a biggie, but when modules start to get packed full of stuff, it would be nice to have some scoping mechanism for relative path resolution.